# C++ изменение глобальной переменной

Tags: c++

Имею такой код

```
char powerUpPDF[3];

void DemoGL::powerUpCheck(){
  powerCheck->toggle();
  char status_OK[] = "OK";
  char status_NO[] = "—"
  if (powerCheck->isChecked()){
      powerUpPDF = status_OK;
     }else{
      powerUpPDF = status_NO;
     }
}
```

По идеи, он должен присваивать powerUpPDF, значение status_OK, но показывает мне ошибку `invalid array assignment`.

Comment: эх... strcpy() используйте, нельзя через = строки присваивать.

Comment: @pavel strcpy(powerUpPDF, status_OK); вот так?

Comment: да (10 символов)

Comment: Зачетные кавычки `„“` в код затесались. Из ворда что ли копировали?

Comment: @alexolut нет, код переписывал в стандартное маковское(не люблю Windows) приложение "Заметки", так как код на одной машине... без сети и тд. :) кросс-компилирование в этом случае пока что не особо работает :)

Comment: В общем, кавычки такие в плюс*а*х невалидны.

Comment: @alexolut это я знаю, тут всего-лишь сработала авто корректирование текста.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для присвоения строк используйте функции `strcpy` или `strncpy`. Вторая функция еще и проконтролирует, чтобы было скопировано не более указанного числа символов

```
if (powerCheck->isChecked()) {
  strcpy(status_OK, powerUpPDF);
} else {
  strncpy(status_NO, powerUpPDF, 3);
}
```